# What is the best way to fully read a stream of objects from a file in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm creating a potentially long log of objects and do not want to keep them all in memory before writing to a file, so I can't write a serialized collection of the objects to a file. I'm trying to find out the 'best' way of reading in the entire stream of objects after logging has been finished.

I have noticed that the following does not work:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(log);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
while ((obj = in.readObject()) != null) {
  // do stuff with obj
}
```

because the stream throws an exception when it reaches the end of a file rather than returning null (presumably because one can write/read null to object streams, causing the above loop not to behave as expected).

Is there a better way to do something like what I want to accomplish with the above loop than:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(log);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
try {
  while (true) {
    obj = in.readObject();
    // do stuff with obj
  }
} catch (EOFException e) {
}
```

This seems a little clumsy. For an end-of-file object solution, is the following the best way?

```
private static final class EOFObject implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

void foo() {
  Object obj;
  while (!((obj = in.readObject()) instanceof EOFObject)) {
    BidRequest bidRequest = ((BidRequestWrapper) obj).getBidRequest();
    bidRequestList.add(bidRequest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution seems fine. Just make sure you have a `finally` clause, where you close your stream.

Alternatively, you can create an EOF object of yours, and add it at the end. Thus you can check if the currently read object is the `EofObject`, and `break` at that point.

Comment: Edited the question to include the EOFObject solution. Is what I've written the best way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @jonderry yup, looks fine. Just remember to close the stream in a `finally` block (you can't avoid that part - so just `try / finally`)

Comment: Cool, is there any tradeoff at all between the EOFObject solution and catching the EOFException?

Comment: @jonderry apart from readability - I don't think so. Generally it is not a good practice to use exceptions to define your program flow, so you are avoiding that. Performance-wise, I guess the difference is negligible, if any. You can measure them with big data.

Comment: I don't understand that. The method throws EOFException at end of stream. So use it.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm creating a potentially long log of objects and do not want to keep them all in memory before writing to a file, so I can't write a serialized collection of the objects to a file

This requirement is not met when using Java serialization, because the serialization stream maintains strong references to the objects previously written, presumably in order to write back references should these objects need to be serialized again. This can be verified by running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 1E9; i++) {
        oos.writeObject(i);
    }
    oos.close();
}
```

A similar problem exists when deserializing the file. To resolve back references, the stream is very likely to keep all previously read objects alive to resolve potential back references to these objects from the serialization stream.

If you really need to be able to release these objects before the stream is fully written you might wish to use <strike>a fresh ObjectOutputStream for each (batch of) objects</strike> `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` - of course losing the capability to resolve back references from earlier streams. That is, the following program will not throw an OutOfMemoryError:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 1E9; i++) {
        oos.writeObject(i);
        oos.reset();
    }
    oos.close();
}
```

Note that the metadata about the classes being serialized will be written anew after each reset, which is quite wasteful (the above program write about 80 bytes per Integer ...), so you should not reset too often, perhaps once every 100 objects?

For detecting the end of stream, I find bozho's suggestion of an EOF object best.

Comment: So even if there are no remaining references to the objects that have been written or their fields, they will not be garbage collected until the stream is closed?

Comment: Yes, because the ObjectOutputStream can't know what other object you want to serialize later, and therefore, neither can the ObjectInputStream.

Comment: Why does it matter what objects will be serialized later if there are no dependencies between the previously written objects and the objects to be written in the future?

Comment: @jonderry Also see [ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()).

Comment: I wonder what happens with all those opened, and not closed, `ObjectOutputStream`s.

Comment: @jonderry: The OOS does not know before whether there will be dependencies, so it has to store references to all objects ever stored (and the ObjectInputStream, too), to be able to restore a graph of objects to an isomorphic graph on the other side. If you know you don't need this (and don't want this), `reset` is the right thing to do here to avoid blocking garbage collection. Creating new ObjectOutpuStreams is not useful, as you then also have to create new ObjectInputStreams at the other end.

Comment: @superfav Is the table mappings object that is getting reset by this method only used to optimize cases in which the same object is written to the stream multiple times?

Comment: @Paulo can you give a trivial example of such a situation, where reset will cause bad things to happen?

Comment: @superfav: good point, I didn't know about that method. It is of course preferred. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @jonderry I think so. You can read more in the [Object Serialization: Frequently Asked Questions](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/serializationFAQ.jsp#handle) page.

Answer (score 2):

Write a `boolean` after each object, with the "last" object being followed by a `false`. So, in your stream that you write out:

```
true
<object>
true
<object>
true
<object>
false
```

Then, when reading them back in, you check the flag (you know there will always be one after each object) to decide whether or not to read another one.

`boolean` will be stored very compactly in a serialization stream, so it shouldn't add much  to the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. readObject() doesn't return null at EOS, it throws EOFException. So catch it. Null is returned if you *wrote* a null. You don't need all the booleans or marker objects suggested above.