# How to read multiple same objects from a file

Tags: java, eclipse, object, serializable

I am trying to read objects from a file(same objects of a class), using Serializable, but whenit reads all objects it gives me error `IOException`, `java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte`.

I am reading objects and then saving to list. But as it reached lets say EOF it throws error.

Here is my method:

```
private static void updateBook(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    Object obj = new Object();
    List<Object> libb = new ArrayList<Object>();
    File file = new File(name + ".ser");
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            try {
                while (true) {

                    obj = in.readObject();
                    libb.add(obj);
                }
            } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
                if (!e.eof) throw e;
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done!");
            } finally {
                in.close();
                //fis.close();
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < libb.size(); ++j) {
                Book li = new Book();

                 li = (Book) libb.get(j);
                System.out.println(li.getBookName());
            }
            //

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nThe file does not Exist!");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to avoid this error from `while(true)`.

Complete error:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to fully read a stream of objects from a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046033/what-is-the-best-way-to-fully-read-a-stream-of-objects-from-a-file-in-java)

Comment: @aribeiro Its different, because I do have finally clause, and still I am getting EOF error.

Comment: True, but you don't have the catch for the `EOFException`.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you. its solved.

Answer (score 1):

On your `try` statement you are missing the catch clause for the `EOFException`:

```
try {
    while (true) {

        obj = in.readObject();
        libb.add(obj);
    }
} catch (OptionalDataException e) {
    if (!e.eof) throw e;
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done!");
} catch (EOFException eofe) {
    // treat it as you like
} finally {
    in.close();
    //fis.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add:

```
catch (EOFException e){
    // do stuffs
}
```

as `EOFException` is not being caught.

Comment: `break cannot be used outside of the loop`

Comment: yeah - didn't realise the position of the `while` loop